# React: Why can User can log out only after refreshing the page?

Tags: reactjs

The following is my code for automatically logging out after 1 minute, but it's not working. Only when i refresh the page its logging out.

Here is my code:

**Login.js**

```
       async logout() {
          localStorage.clear();
           window.location = "/";
        }


        const login_time = localStorage.getItem("login_time");
        const session = localStorage.getItem("session_id");

        const difference = new Date().getTime() - new Date(time).getTime();
        const minutes = Math.floor(difference/1000/60);

        if(session != null) {
            if(minutes >= 1) {
                this.logout();
            }
        }
```

How can I logout automatically after 1 minute?

Comment: location.href not location

Comment: When does this code actually execute?  If this only executes once on login then `if(minutes >= 1)` is probably `false`.  Do you ever execute this code again at a later time?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `setTimeout` or something similar to execute the logout code at a later time

Comment: Used `setTimeout` and it's working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
onLogin() {
    // after successfully logging in

    setTimeout(logout, 60000):
}
```

Basically, we are setting a timer that executes the `logout()` method after one minute (60000 ms) since login.

Answer (score 0):

window.location is an object.

Try using **location.href**.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp